# Tailwind would not load in a new nextjs app... Unexpected character '@'

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

I used the "create-next-app" to make my new Nextjs project. I selected tailwindcss in the installer, but when I try to run app with npm run dev, Ill get this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
> @import 'tailwindcss/base';
| @import 'tailwindcss/components';
| @import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

I hope there are smart people out there that can give me answer... :)

I will paste the code below:

Layout.js:

```js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

page.js:

```js
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

next.config.mjs

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};


export default nextConfig;
```

Edit:
Tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

New edit:

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTQ54.png)

Packages:
{
"name": "camping-fullstack",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"next": "14.1.4",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18"
},
"devDependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
"eslint": "^8",
"eslint-config-next": "14.1.4",
"postcss": "^8.4.38",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
}
}

Comment: You got a `tailwind.config.js` file?

Comment: Also are you pasting the `@import`s manually?

Comment: Try reinstalling the nextjs app because the latest version of nextjs, i.e. Nextjs 14 automatically installs tailwind for you

Comment: Then try installing tailwind manually using the npm command

Comment: This is so weird... i follow tailwind's guide for next, but when i use npm the app can't find tailwind css dependencies. When I use yarn, tyhe original problem

Comment: can you update your question showing the error and your package file?

Comment: i did, any idea?

Comment: Going back and forth between yarn can create tons of issues if you don't clear the node_modules and lock files first. Yarn uses a global cache and can store dependencies outside of your node_modules folder and use the yarn-lock file to locate them. Npm doesn't do that by default, pnpm would store it's dependencies in a different location. If my answer below doesn't solve this for you, delete the node_modules folder and the yarn-lock and/or package-lock file, and then install with only one of those package managers. I'd set the packageManager option in package.json to prevent this in the future

Comment: my solution was consistent use of yarn, and not npm

Answer (score 0):

That error seems odd, because imports should be allowed, but it's possible that it's just an inaccurate message. What you're looking for in this case isn't an import, it's a directive that Tailwind itself supplies:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: This was not the problem... the solution was consistent use of yarn, and not npm